# Filtering logic in Javascript - looking for range of values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Struggling to get my head around the logic/syntax needed here, so hoping someone cleverer than me can help :-)

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of the 'Bedrooms' slider shown here: https://www.redrow.co.uk/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&category=&item_id=&search_type=text&advanced_search=true&term=birmingham&x=0&y=0&distance=20&min-beds=1&price-min=0&price-max=100000000&house_type=

You'll see that a search brings back a list of property developments which have various attributes, one of which is the number of bedrooms houses in that development could have, eg. "2, 3 & 4 bedroom homes" or "1, 3 & 4 bedroom homes".

In the search filters at the top of the page there is a 'Bedrooms' slider. The maximum value is fixed to 6+ but the minimum value is user selectable. So when the slider handle is on, say '3', that filters down to all developments with properties that have 3 bedrooms or more. The part I'm having trouble with is that a development - as an example shown in the results above, let's say the 'Chestnut Walk' development - has 3 and 4 bedroom properties, but it also has 2 bedroom properties which would be filtered out by placing the slider at '3'.

In my JSON object I have an array of available bedrooms for each development, so for example a development with "2, 3 & 4 bedroom homes" would have an array of ['2','3','4']. What I *think* I need to do is check if **any** of the values in the array fall within the minimum and maximum number of bedrooms as per the slider - but as a bit of a JS novice I can't for the life of me work out how I would do that efficiently. Can anyone help?!

Comment: if your code isn't too large, could you post it in the question?

Comment: Could you please narrow down your post to the essential parts? I'm struggling to find out what of it is relevant, and what isn't.

Comment: Is your question essentially: I have an array of numbers and I have a min and max value. I want to know how to check if a min or max value show up in that array?

Comment: Hi @aquinas, no I think what I need to do is check if any value between min and max shows up in the array...?

Comment: @lxg sorry, I think because I'm so confused by it I'm struggling to explain it clearly! I was trying to explain how the logic works in the example, in order to ask how I can replicate it with my data, so I'd say it's all relevant but is rather complex :-/

Comment: I think you should try to reduce the problem to the smallest, reproducible unit, and post it here (new post). This will guarantee that either you find the solution yourself, or somebody can reproduce it and suggest a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the minLimit as the minimum number of rooms selected in slider then :

```
for(var i=0; i<noOfRoomsArray.length; i++){
  if(noOfRoomsArray[i] >= minLimit){
  //this is a valid choice of client
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the js math function min() and max() on arrays.